# thinnest way to create a remote branch

Tags: git, bash

I'm looking for the cheapest and thinnest possible way to create a new branch on the remote from master.

My use case is simple - via automation I need to *create a new branch on the remote, from master, which developers can then check out and begin working on a feature*.  (We are doing this in automation to enforce naming conventions, etc.) There is no intention of actually working in the local clone - the sole purpose is to create a new remote branch from the HEAD of master.

I've learned it's not possible to do this without first cloning the repo locally, but I'd like the process to be as fast as possible.

I've come up with the following.

```
git clone --depth 1 -b master --single-branch https://me@bitbucket.org/me/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
git push origin master:feature_x
```

After which I would cleanup with:

```
cd ..
rm -rf myrepo
```

Is this the fastest, most lightweight and simplest approach?  Are there any huge sinkholes I could fall in with this approach?

Comment: The `git push origin master:feature_x` concerns me greatly, as that is pushing the contents of `feature_x` into your `master` branch.  That *really* doesn't sound like what you want even if you think it is.  Are you just interested in creating throwaway branches on your remote?

Comment: no, and yes it may be totally wrong.  I've updated the question with more clarity of what I need.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I must say though, using automation to create the branches for you out of naming conventions alone is a bit of a concern.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I've greatly simplified the scenario to just my exact question - in truth its part of a much larger CD workflow where feature branches are created automatically by the ALM platform, all work is tracked until the feature is 'done', then downstream automation carries the feature to its eventual deployment into production.  It's quite awesome if I do say so myself!

Comment: The easiest way would be `ssh $remotehost 'cd /path/to/repo; git branch feature_x'`.

Answer (score 2):

I would not delete the repo after the push.

I would keep it, and refresh it when needed (`git fetch --depth=1`), in order to use it again for the next feature branch to create on the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, the fastest and less secure way to create a branch on a remote repository is to do in the bare repository folder on the server something like that:

```
git rev-parse master >> ./refs/heads/mynewbranch
```

No clone needed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> create a new branch on the remote, from master, which developers can then check out and begin working on a feature

Easy: have the developers create the branch themselves, in their own repos.  You can supply any tools you want to invent branch names, but refnames are repo-local.  What matters is the commits, not what this repo or that calls them.